# Error trying to load a JSON string in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am new to Python and reading about this it seems to be very easy but for some reason I am unable to debug the error. I am guessing it is something very simple...

2 Functions

`def get_json():
    return json.load(open('environment.json', 'r'))`

`def curlopia(j_son=get_json()):
    sf_url = j_son['sf_sandbox_url']['url']
    grant_type = j_son['oauth_parms']['grant_type']
    client_id = j_son['oauth_parms']['client_id']
    client_secret = j_son['oauth_parms']['client_secret']
    username = j_son['oauth_parms']['username']
    password = j_son['oauth_parms']['password']
    param = '-d'`

I have a curl statement in a subprocess.call which returns a json string.

`x=subrpocess.call(["curl", sf_url, param, "grant_type=%s" % (grant_type), param, "client_id=%s" % (client_id), param, "client_secret=%s" % (client_secret), param, "username=%s" % (username), param, "password=%s" % (password)])`

or

`x=os.system('curl {0} -d "grant_type={1}" -d "client_id={2}" -d "client_secret={3}" -d "username={4}" -d "password={5}" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"'.format(sf_url, grant_type, client_id, client_secret, username, password))`

When I print x the result is with trailing zero at the end.

`{"id":"https://blah@blah.blah/","issued_at":"xxxxxxxxxxx","token_type":"Bearer","instance_url":"xxxxxxxxxx","signature":"xxxxxxxxx","access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}0`

Unsure why.

when I do

`json.loads(x)`

gives me the below error. Also I have tried various combinations

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 360, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

I am trying to understand why there is a trailing zero and if the error is related to that.If is the case can someone suggest a way around it and maybe the correct method of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: you are apparently trying to load invalid JSON, the zero at the end will break it. No idea what you have in `curl statement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load invalid JSON document.

From your reference to curl I guess, you need to get this document by some http request.

Try getting it by using `requests` library.

```
import requests
url = "http://example.com/api"
req = requests.get(url)
assert req.ok
data = req.json()
print data
```

You real case might require different url, method (POST...) and possibly headers, but these you shall already know from your existing curl statement)

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right about the invalid JSON. 

When I use the same curl statement in the terminal I get a valid JSON. An invalid JSON is returned from only the python script and I am able to see it when I print the result returned from a subprocess.call or os.system. 

I have also checked the encoding of the .json file and tried both UTF-8 and UTF-16. Unfortunately both yield the same results. I have updated the initial question to reflect the curl statement.

Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: With the updates to question if you reckon I have to post a new question I will do that. Cheers

Comment: Although this is not what I did to fix the issue, I am agreeing to the response.